# Scrapy-Playwright: TypeError: ProactorEventLoop is not supported, got: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False

Tags: scrapy, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to use Scrapy-Playwright in my windows but I am getting `TypeError: ProactorEventLoop is not supported, got: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False` this error. What is the reason behind it?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine
import playwright


class PlaySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'play'


    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://quotes.toscrape.com/js",
            meta= dict(
                playwright= True,
                playwright_include_page= True,
                playwright_page_coroutines= [
                    PageCoroutine('wait_for_selector', 'div.quote')
                    ]
        ))

    async def parse(self, response):
        text = response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']/span/text()")
        yield {
            'Quotes': text.get()
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you'll have to use WSL for now: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright/issues/7#issuecomment-817394494

Comment: @DMalan I have using anaconda on my windows. If I install WSL, do I need to install anaconda again under wsl? I have zero knowledge on WSL